# Angular js / ionic app url links and function links not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I'm working on a angular js / ionic based app, I'm new with this.

In my app I retrieve Strava data and inject it into a div via .append();
This is what I have in .append():

```
$("#list").append("<div><p>some text <a href='https://www.strava.com/athletes/...' target='_blank'>url_link</a></p><p><a on-tap='myFunction()'>trigger_function_link</a></p></div>");
```

The above code on it's self is working fine except for two things in it.
(1)When I press the first link the URL is opend in a new page in my browser but not in my app.
 I tried different things (org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser, javascript, angular js solutions) but non is working.

(2)When I press the second link, the on-tap function is not getting triggered.

When I copy paste the above div directly in my HTML (so it's not injected) everything is working fine, url links are opent in new page or in my native browser app on my device and the angular on-tap function is triggered correctly.

```
<div><p>some text <a href='https://www.strava.com/athletes/...' target='_blank'>url_link</a></p><p><a on-tap='Strava()'>trigger_function_link</a></p></div>
```

Now the big question is how come that when my code is injected with .append() my links are not working, and is there a fix?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use jQuery for which angular has already written a directive for it.

I'd suggest you to use `ng-if` directive, do keep that div inside your html with some flag like `showDiv`. Whenever the `showDiv` is `true` at that time div will get added into the DOM(shown on html) & when that flag is false div will get removed from the DOM(will get hidden)

```
<div ng-if="showDiv">
  <p>some text <a href='https://www.strava.com/athletes/...' target='_blank'>url_link</a></p>
  <p><a on-tap='myFunction()'>trigger_function_link</a></p>
</div>
```

**Update**

You are getting data from ajax(Ajax call should be done using `$http` rather than using jQuery), store that data in $scope.objs = data & appending the same `div` for multiple number of times, I'd suggest you to use `ng-repeat` to render all `div`s that would be more efficient way.

```
<div id="list">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
        <p>{{obj.clubmember}}<a href='strava.com/athletes/...' ; target='_blank'>url_link</a></p>
        <p><a on-tap='myFunction()'>trigger_function_link</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! I have strava data in an array with 20 items and I use an .forEach loop function to get data from strava and insert it in the main div. with .append() Is this also possible with your code ?

Comment: how are you render those 20 items? using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No I have a simple div <div id='list'></div> and than with the following code in javascript I pull strava data and populate it in the #list div $.getJSON(stravaClubActivities, function(data) {data.forEach(function(obj) {$("#list").append("<div><p>"+ obj.clubmember+"<a href='https://www.strava.com/athletes/...' target='_blank'>url_link</a></p><p><a on-tap='myFunction()'>trigger_function_link</a></p></div>");});

Comment: So you should use $http instead of `$.getJSON` & you could use `ng-repeat` for rendering data on UI

Comment: you have to forget Jquery development method for AngularJS databinding.
Append content is not the proper way to do it in angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Append content is not a standard AngularJS.
IF you'd like to "append HTML", please refer to provider [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Otherwise, you shall define your content into a AngularJS HTML template as offered by @pankajparkar